# How to see if a list is sorted in common lisp?

Tags: lisp

How do I determine if a list is sorted in ascending order in common lisp? Am I on the right track?

```
(defun is-sorted (lst)
  (cond
    ((null lst ) T) 
    ((<= car lst (lst cdr lst)))
    ((is-sorted (cdr lst) nil))))

(print (is-sorted '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)))
```

Comment: You should post your code here instead of a link.

Comment: I have been having trouble formatting it correctly.

Comment: You need to have four spaces in front of every line to format it as code. There is also a button for it (the one with curly braces)

Answer (score 5):

You want to go through the list and at each step check that the current element is not bigger than the next.  If it is, you can skip the rest and return false.  If you reach the end, return true.

```
(defun sortedp (list)
  (cond ((endp (rest list)) t)  ; end of the list: success
        ((> (first list) (second list)) nil)  ; first two not sorted: fail
        (t (sortedp (rest list)))))  ; go to next two
```

You can do this more succinctly with `every`:

```
(defun sortedp (list)
  (every #'<= list (rest list)))
```